# How to calculate the page size of a system?

Tags: virtual-memory, page-size

Given 32kb physical memory, 16-bit virtual address, and 12 bit used as offset. How do I calculate the page size of the system?

I have look up for a lot of solution online but none of them could help me solve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The physical memory is extraneous data. All you need is the 16 and 12 to find the answer.

Comment: It is 2^12=4096. The answer is 4kb?